# How to match a Spring @RequestMapping having a @pathVariable containing "/"?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am doing the following request from the client:

`/search/hello%2Fthere/`

where the search term "hello/there" has been URLencoded.

On the server I am trying to match this URL using the following request mapping:

```
@RequestMapping("/search/{searchTerm}/") 
public Map searchWithSearchTerm(@PathVariable String searchTerm) {
// more code here 
}
```

But I am getting error 404 on the server, due I don't have any match for the URL. I noticed that the URL is decoded before Spring gets it. Therefore is trying to match /search/hello/there which does not have any match.

I found a Jira related to this problem here: http://jira.springframework.org/browse/SPR-6780 .But I still don't know how to solve my problem.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 28, accepted):

There are no good ways to do it (without dealing with `HttpServletResponse`). You can do something like this:

```
@RequestMapping("/search/**")  
public Map searchWithSearchTerm(HttpServletRequest request) { 
    // Don't repeat a pattern
    String pattern = (String)
        request.getAttribute(HandlerMapping.BEST_MATCHING_PATTERN_ATTRIBUTE);  

    String searchTerm = new AntPathMatcher().extractPathWithinPattern(pattern, 
        request.getServletPath());

    ...
}
```

Comment: For me instead of request.getServletPath() worked request.getPathInfo()

Comment: AntPathMatcher is thread-safe. Sharing an instance is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
    @Configuration
    public class AdditionalWebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {
     .......
     ...........
     ...........
    @Override
    public void configureContentNegotiation(ContentNegotiationConfigurer 
    configurer) {
       configurer.favorPathExtension(false);
    }
    .......
    .......
  }
```

**and add regex like this in @PathVariable("user/{username:.+}")**