# @RequestMapping controllers and dynamic URLs

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I would like to use Spring MVC `@RequestMapping` annotation to attach my controller to requests in such way:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value="/prod/{value:.+}/show")
 public String getProduct(
        @PathVariable("value") String value, 
        ModelMap modelMap, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) { 
        ...
 }
```

and when request will be

```
(..)/prod/foo/show
```

my value variable will have `foo`

and when request will be

```
(..)/prod/foo/bar/show
```

my value variable will have `foo/bar` etc

Is there any way to do that? What `@RequestMapping` wildcards are supported?

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2334787/how-to-match-a-spring-requestmapping-having-a-pathvariable-containing

Comment: Yes - it doesnt do actually what i need :( Already checked other ways here on SO

Comment: It got fixed in Spring 3.1

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions. All though you might have to do some escaping. Check out [this jira ticket](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-7787).

Comment: What is the default pattern used to parse @RequestMapping params? I've already put dots (like above) to be included.

Is that pattern built in somehow incremental way or absolute and i must define all regex from the scratch?

Comment: could you clarify what you mean by incremental vs. absolute?

Comment: i mean if i put some regex there will it overwrite default pattern or be combined with it

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you well that you need to pass from your view to the controller a String, for example, that contains some wild character.
When you receive this String on the controller you will just find the values before your wild character.

This behavior makes sense as you can't add "." or "/" ,"#" into url .
If you are using a freemarker , you can do this by using ?url :http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/docs/ref_builtins_string.html#ref_builtin_url

Additionally, the ".",the dot as you can see here : http://www.december.com/html/spec/esccodes.html
doesn't have  ASCII hexadecimal equivalent code so you will need to alter it from the code to be something like "#" to be passed from the view to the controller.

Comment: Regarding the nasty workaround I told you about,using #,forget it and use that :http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?78085-Problems-with-RequestMapping&p=263563#post263563