# Spring MVC Url pattern

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I was wondering if I can customize my url into controller to accept null values

```
@RequestMapping(
            value = "foo/{y}/{x}",
            method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView doSmth(@PathVariable(value = "x") String x,
                               @PathVariable(value = "y") String y) {
}
```

Here in my case , X , Y can be empty string .
How could I manage smth like that to let this method on the controller to handle this url ?

Comment: what are all combinations of X and Y? Is it possible to split it to many methods - preprocess variables and do logic in some common private method?

Comment: BTW: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5879666/requestmapping-controlers-and-dynamic-urls

Answer (score 1):

If you want to support optional values, then path variables aren't well suited. Request parameters (using `@RequestParam`) are a better idea, since they easily support optional values using the `required` attribute.

If you really want to support optional path variables, then you need to overload your mappings, i.e.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "foo/{y}/{x}")
public ModelAndView doSmth(@PathVariable(value = "x") String x, @PathVariable(value = "y") String y) 

@RequestMapping(value = "foo/{y}")
public ModelAndView doSmth(@PathVariable(value = "y") String y) 

@RequestMapping(value = "foo")
public ModelAndView doSmth()
```

Comment: The thing is this url contains mulible fields that may contain empty string not null . If I follow this methodology , I will need to write many overloads methods . I need to avoid this !!

Comment: @Echo: Yes, that's why I just said use `@RequestParam` instead.

Comment: I am trying to support it using @RequestMapping 
/foo/${x}/[#if x?has_content]${y} [#else] What I can do to pass empty String [/#if]

Comment: So is there any advice how to pass empty string !!

Comment: @Echo: You're not listening to me - path variables *are not suited* to this kind of logic.

Comment: u are right that @RequestMapping can't be suited to handle my case . I was just needed to avoid writing multiple overloaded methods .Also @Whiteship , the one who suggested a solution below, may has an interesting solution . However , I have maintained my code a little bit in order not to call my method with multiple url variables .Thanks @skaffman for ur amazing assistance

Answer (score 1):

I don't think, that's a good URL. It can be very confusing to users.

Why don't you try this one?

```
@RequestMapping("foo/x/{x}/y/{y}")
public ModelAndView doSmth(@PathVariable String x, @PathVariable String y)
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't try it as I have used another methodology but ur solution is interesting to be tried .