# Use @RequestMapping with Dynamic URL at Controller Level

Tags: java, spring, controller, dynamic-url

I've been doing my fair amount of research through Stack Overflow and Google and the closest I found was something like [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5879666/requestmapping-controllers-and-dynamic-urls) but still it does not answer my question. The documentation for @RequestMapping doesn't say anything about the possibilities of using dynamic URLs at the controller level so I was wondering if something like the code below is possible:

```
@RequestMapping("/something/{somethingsId}")
public class ExampleController{
    //Some methods mapping to some endpoints that start with /something/{somethingsId}
    @GetMapping("/getOtherThing")
    public ResponseEntity<> getOtherThing(@PathVariable("somethingsId")String somethingsId){
        //Do something with somethingsId
    }
}
```

This is just an example code of what I intend to achieve. I want to do this to separate some functionalities into different controllers that need this somethingsId to be able to work but I don't know if what I want is possible or if I will have to content myself with repeating the same thing in every method of the controller to get that **"somethingsId"** path variable.

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can achive it, follow the same way as I mentioned

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/owners/{ownerId}")
public class Test {

    @RequestMapping("/pets/{petId}")
    public void findPet(@PathVariable String ownerId, @PathVariable String petId, Model model) {
        System.out.println("ownerId "+ownerId+" petId "+petId);
    }
}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly I think, tested it already and it's a relief that this works. Documentation or examples on the internet don't quite reflect that this usage is possible, at least not where I searched for.