# Spring 3.1.RC1 and PATH_WITHIN_HANDLER_MAPPING_ATTRIBUTE

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Posted in [spring forum](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?116567-Spring-3.1.RC1-and-PATH_WITHIN_HANDLER_MAPPING_ATTRIBUTE) with no response.

I have the following code snippet (from [here](http://code.google.com/p/pls-generator/source/browse/src/main/java/net/sourceforge/jukebox/web/MediaBrowser.java)), which is part of my [pet project](http://code.google.com/p/pls-generator).

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/browse")
public class MediaBrowser {
   ...

    @RequestMapping("/**")
    public final ModelAndView listContents(final HttpServletRequest request) {

        String folder = (String) request.getAttribute(
                HandlerMapping.PATH_WITHIN_HANDLER_MAPPING_ATTRIBUTE);
                ...
    }
```

I access the following url:

http://localhost:8080/myapp/browse

- In spring `3.0.6.RELEASE`, I got the `folder` variable as `null`, which is the expected value.
- In spring `3.1.RC1`, the `folder` variable is `/browse`.

Is this a bug or has something changed in spring-3.1?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As skaffman said, you probably shouldn't use `PATH_WITHIN_HANDLER_MAPPING_ATTRIBUTE`. Take a look at [How to match a Spring @RequestMapping having a @pathVariable containing "/"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2334787/how-to-match-a-spring-requestmapping-having-a-pathvariable-containing) for an example of using `AntPathMatcher` to accomplish what you are trying

Comment: Like `PATH_WITHIN_HANDLER_MAPPING_ATTRIBUTE`, the suggested alternate `BEST_MATCHING_PATTERN_ATTRIBUTE` is also an internal framework internal implementation details, which is not expected to be relied on.  However, it works and so I am accepting the answer.

Answer (score 3):

This looks very much like an internal implementation detail of the framework, one that you should not be relying on.

The javadoc for `PATH_WITHIN_HANDLER_MAPPING_ATTRIBUTE` says:

> Note: This attribute is not required to be supported by all `HandlerMapping` implementations. URL-based HandlerMappings will typically support it, but handlers should not necessarily expect this request attribute to be present in all scenarios.

I wouldn't be surprised if the behaviour changed slightly between 3.0 and 3.1.

Comment: Thanks. I have seen the javadoc and realize it is unreliable. Perhaps someone can suggest an alternate solution - essentially a way to specify folder names in REST-style URL. Got this one from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3686808/spring-3-requestmapping-get-path-value