# How to create a @RequestMapping @PathVariable to include a / in the parameter?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-el

Is there a way in Spring 3.x to have a PathVariable in a request mapping include a forward /?  I've tried different regexs that I thought would have parsed properly, but it seems that they never manage to pick up the forward /.

I found [this related SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2334787/827480) question, but that is more dependent on URL encoding of parameters, which is not exactly my problem.

I've tried the following @RequestMapping but to no avail:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/template/{definitionName:[a-zA-Z0-9_./]+}/{attributeName:.+}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@RequestMapping(value = "/template/{definitionName}/{attributeName:[^/]+}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

For example, I am trying to match the following URLs:

```
http://localhost:8880/mustache/template/users/info/user_info.updateable
```

where

- "users/info" would be definitionName
- "user_info.updateable" would be attributeName

The full method prototype would be:

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/template/{definitionName:[a-zA-Z0-9_./]+}/{attributeName:.+}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public static void fetchTemplateDefinition(
            @PathVariable("definitionName") final String definitionName,
            @PathVariable("attributeName") final String attributeName,
            final HttpServletRequest request,
            final HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
    {...}
```

Is there any way to match parameters that contain a / in the URL?

Comment: Your first regex will fail because . matches any character and regexes are "greedy" by default so the `definitionName` part will match `users/info/user_info.updateable` with nothing left for the `attributeName`

Comment: @Taylor Actually, '.' in a character set is supposed to be the literal '.' character; not the wildcard.  But that still does not explain why the second regex does not work.

Comment: Your intent may be the literal . character but unless you escape it, that's not what it is.

Comment: @Taylor - Are you sure about that?  To my knowledge, Regex character sets are literal - hence [.] would be the '.' character and not the wildcard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible out of the box. Spring calls `PathMatcher.extractUriTemplateVariables()` to extract the path variables. The default implementation of `PathMatcher` is `AntPathMatcher` and that splits the path and the path pattern into pieces using `/`as a separator.

The only solution would be to implement your own `PathMatcher` (or extend the `AntPathMatcher`) and tell Spring to use it.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  Any idea how one configures the PathMatcher in Spring 3.2?  `AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter` has been deprecated in exchanged for `RequestMappingHandlerAdapter` which does not have the `PathMatcher`.  The only place I found it was in the `WebContentInterceptor`.  Is that the correct place?  How does one configure the `WebContentInterceptor`?

Comment: @EricB. `RequestMappingHandlerMapping`

Comment: Am I missing something?  I don't see it anywhere in the RequestMappingHandlerMapping to set the PathMatcher.

Comment: @EricB. The method itself is defined in the abstract base class `AbstractHandlerMapping`