# Spring @RequestMapping handling of special characters

Tags: java, spring, rest, url, urlencode

I have a REST API like this:

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/services/produce/{_id}", method = RequestMethod.PATCH, 
  consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
  public String patchObject(@RequestBody PatchObjectRequest obj, 
      @PathVariable("_id") String id) {
  // some code
  }
```

My problem is that the id that might be given is in the form:

```
US%2FCA%2FSF%2FPlastic
```

Which is a URL encoding of "US/CA/SF/Plastic".

My problem is that when a % character is put into the URL the @RequestMapping does not map it to this method and it will return a 404. Is there a way to accept ids that have % character in them as part of the URL?

Comment: Can you show us an example of it failing? I'd like to see a request to a specific URL with those characters and Spring logs showing that it didn't find a mapper.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are receiving this error because using it as path variable it is decoded and then server tries to match it to a path that doesn't exits. Similar questions where posted a few years ago: [How to match a Spring @RequestMapping having a @pathVariable containing "/"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2334787/how-to-match-a-spring-requestmapping-having-a-pathvariable-containing), [urlencoded Forward slash is breaking URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3235219/urlencoded-forward-slash-is-breaking-url).

A good option for you would be to change `_id` from `@PathVariable` to `@RequestParam` and problem solved, and remove it from path.

Comment: This solution won't work if your intention is to identify the pattern that is used in the URI for the incoming request.

Answer (score 3):

Hope you can add regex in the path variable like:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/services/produce/{_id:.+}", 
  method = RequestMethod.PATCH, 
  consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, 
  produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
```