# RequestMapping with String parameter containing URL

Tags: java, spring, html, request-mapping

I have a Spring controller with two parameter long and String:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/webpage")
@Controller
public class WebpageContentController {
//...
    @RequestMapping(value = "{webpageId}/{webpageAddress}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String contentWebpageById(@PathVariable long webpageId, @PathVariable String webpageAddress) {
        System.out.println("webpageId=" + webpageId);
        System.out.println("webpageAddress=" + webpageAddress);
        //...
    }
//...
```

If I invoke it like this:

```
http://localhost:8080/webarch/webpage/1/blahblah
```

All is fine:

```
webpageId=1
webpageAddress=blahblah
```

But If I pass String parameter with slash (in this case URL address):

```
http://localhost:8080/webarch/webpage/1/https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page
```

I get an error:

```
org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound.noHandlerFound No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/webarch/webpage/1/https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page] in DispatcherServlet with name 'appServlet'
```

How pass such parameter?

Comment: There is no easy way to do this. The WebMVC maintainers have explicitly refused requests to support it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well the error is caused by springs controllers mapping, when Spring sees url like

```
http://localhost:8080/webarch/webpage/1/https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page
```

It doesn't 'know' that the 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page' should be mapped as parameter to "{webpageId}/{webpageAddress}" mapping since every slash is interpreted as a  deeper controler method mapping. It looks for controller method mapping like `(webpage/1/http:{anotherMapping}/wiki{anotherMapping}/Main_Page{anotherMapping})` wich this kind of mapping is obviously not handled by "{webpageId}/{webpageAddress}"

**EDIT**

According to your comment you can try something like this

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{webpageId}/**", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String contentWebpageById(HttpServletRequest request) {

    String pattern = (String) request.getAttribute(HandlerMapping.BEST_MATCHING_PATTERN_ATTRIBUTE);  

    String extractedPathParam = pathMatcher.extractPathWithinPattern(pattern, request.getServletPath());
    extractedPathParam = extractedPathParam.replace("http:/", "http://");
    extractedPathParam = extractedPathParam.replace("https:/", "https://");
    //do whatever you want with parsed string..
}
```

Using spring 4.2.1

SomeParsing should use some Regular Expression to extract only the URL 'variable'

Comment: I wanted to do GET method like this (don't POST): `https://web.archive.org/web/20150609000851/http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page`
There is no way to do this? Maybe value mapping with `*` or custom `@RequestMapping`?

Comment: Yes this work, thanks. But with this solution I must parse URL, because I getting `/webarch/webpage/1/https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page` instead of `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page`. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2335449/2442133) I found solution that give me `https:/en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page`. I don't know why `https://` is replaced with `https:/` (one slash fewer).

Comment: @mkr321 i updated my answer to exactly fit your needs, it will always merge slashes into maximm one slash because this is how  RequestMapping works

Answer (score 1):

Just encode all special characters in the URL.

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page
```

becomes this:

```
https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FMain_Page
```

and you can pass it as URL parameter without any problems. Decoding is done automatically, so if you access the parameter as variable in your controller, it contains the URL already decoded and you can use it without any converting needed.

More information about URL encoding: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding