# How to pass @PathVariable("timeZoneId") in spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data, path-variables

I have the following `@RestController` method in Spring Boot 1.5.9:

```java
@GetMapping(value = "/today/{timeZoneId}", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public Instant getToday(@PathVariable("timeZoneId") String timeZoneId) {
  return getNextPublishingDateTime(Instant.now(), timeZoneId);
}
```

When I `GET` with `/today/Europe/Paris`, I have a `404` error.

I tried to `GET` with `/today/Europe%2FParis` but also got a `404`.

This is due to the slash in the `timeZoneId`.

How can I use `@PathVariable` for my `timeZoneId` in Spring ?

Comment: Are you *really* wanting to put that in path ? In REST philosophy, path variables should represent resources. Here, the time-zone would be more suited as a query parameter (as it is only a formatting configuration).

Comment: Why not use timeZoneId as a request parameter? Duplicate of this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2334787/how-to-match-a-spring-requestmapping-having-a-pathvariable-containing

Comment: It doesn't have to be a resource, as for instance : `/profile/{username}` is not a resource, and you can check the principal against the username. I agree in general. So far I use `?timeZoneId`, but this question should be taken as a general question about the way of using path variable that include slash.

Comment: Responding to your comment, this might assist you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3235219/urlencoded-forward-slash-is-breaking-url
Thing is, you cannot pass forward slashes and a few other characters in the url as part of path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible way can be as below,

```
@GetMapping(value = "/today/{timeZoneIdPrefix}/{timeZoneIdSuffix}", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public Instant getToday(@PathVariable("timeZoneIdPrefix") String timeZoneIdPrefix,@PathVariable("timeZoneIdSuffix") String timeZoneIdSuffix) {
  String timeZoneId = timeZoneIdPrefix +"/"+ timeZoneIdSuffix;
  return getNextPublishingDateTime(Instant.now(), timeZoneId);
}
```

One more way could be, instead of passing like Europe/Paris pass as Europe-Paris and then replace `-` with `/`

```
 return getNextPublishingDateTime(Instant.now(), timeZoneId.replace("-","/"));
```

Comment: I tought about that and it's kind of my favorite solution.. after `?timeZoneId`

Answer (score 0):

You get 404 because Spring is expected a only one value after the slash (encoded %2F or not), but in your case you put two values : Europe and Paris.

Comment: The encoded does not work as one param, it just fail because it doesn't decode